# JavaScript - how to check if Object has a certain key, when key is variable?

Tags: javascript

Example:

```
var o = {'key': 'value'};
var key = 'key';
console.log('key' in o); //true
console.log(key in o); //false
```

How to do this? =)

Comment: The second log is `true` as well. Providing a string literal directly or a variable containing a string value has the same effect.

Comment: Both should be true. With what did you test?

Comment: What a ridiculous question and answers...

Comment: Lol actually I made this post by mistake - @amadeus is right =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
o.hasOwnProperty(key);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/TKTkW/).

References:

- [`hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Comment: I am an *evil* ninja... ;)

Comment: And what exactly does this answer?

Comment: I was under the impression that this answered the question: 'how [can I] check if Object has a certain key, when [that] key is [a] variable?' Does it not?

Answer (score 3):

Try `hasOwnProperty`:

```
o.hasOwnProperty(key);
```